# I cannot start JVM

Tags: python, jpype

The last step does not run.

All other steps run.

```
self.__jvm_path = getDefaultJVMPath()
if not isJVMStarted():
    class_path = "-Djava.class.path="
    class_path += "./third_part/java/hLDAForSummary.jar"
    class_path += ";third_part/java/stanford_seg/stanford-segmenter-3.6.0.jar"
    class_path += ";third_part/java/stanford_seg/stanford-segmenter-3.6.0-sources.jar"
    startJVM(self.__jvm_path, "-ea", class_path)
```

Comment: What error message are you given?
What is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Uninstall JDK and remove any environment variables of JAVA_Home.
2. Install Latest version of JDK and don't worry about environment variables because it automatically does.
3. Install Javabridge package in Python.

```
pip install javabridge
```

4.Javabridge might require numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

5.now try to import javabridge in python.

```
import javabridge
```

if successfully imported without any error of unable to start jvm or jvm.dll then your problem is solved.